# How to add custom lightning web components to communities using ExperienceBundle Metadata Api?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, json, metadata-api, lightning-community

I am trying to add custom lightning web components programmatically on community using ExperienceBundle Metadata API and then deploy it to org using Salesforce CLI.
I tried modifying the home.json file under views folder with the required components name.But the deployment is failing with unexpected error:

**Error An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 525381088-168263 (1952124730)
ERROR running force:source:deploy: Deploy failed.**

I have raised a case towards Salesforce regarding this unexpected error. 
Salesforce provided the error Id details as:

**"EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input".**

STEPS TO REPRODUCE:
1.Enable ExperienceBundle Metadata API in your org

2.Create Community using Salesforce CLI

3.Retrieve Community(ExperienceBundle) using Salesforce CLI

4.Modify "force-app\main\default\experiences(CommunityName)1\views\home.json" locally with your custom lightning web components names

5.Try Deploying the modified community using
"sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath "~\force-app\main\default\experiences(CommunityName)1.site-meta.xml"

Comment: Does the deployment succeed when you do not add the lightning web component? What is the API Version being used in package.xml?

Comment: Hi @Swetha, the API version being used is 48.0.What we are doing is : creating community using sfdx , retrieving it , then manipulating the home.json to add our custom components on the community and then deploying it. If we just create , retrieve and deploy without any manipulation the deployment succeeds.